# Do I have to explicitly move members when move-constructing an object?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Assume we have a type `A` with a member that understands move semantics and we wish to implement move semantics for `A` as well;

```
struct A {
  ::std::vector<int> ints;
  A(A&&);
};
```

When implementing `A::A(A&&)` do we have to explicitly `::std::move` the `ints` member or will it be passed as `::std::vector<int>&&` automatically? That is, will these do the same:

```
A(A&& a) : ints(a.ints) {}              // version 1
A(A&& a) : ints(::std::move(a.ints)) {} // version 2
```

Comment: Yes, you have to use `std::move` (or use the `defualt` move constructor.) I'm looking for a suitable duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I wasn't sure so I first looked for a questions that gave a definite answer to this but didn't find one. If you have more luck, feel free to close as dupe.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11

Comment: Rvalue reference parameters and variables are (as id-expressions) lvalues. So are data members (class-member-access-expressions) of lvalues. Therefore, `a.ints` is an lvalue, and `ints(a.ints)` will invoke the *copy* constructor.

Comment: @bitmask Yes, unfortunately a lot of the dupes have poor titles. I am pretty sure I have answered similar questions at least twice. Anyway, I found a reasonable duplicate.